# GDAL error with renv virtual environment in R

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, r, terra

I recently started using renv (on a Mac) to manage project environments and I’ve noticed a troublesome problem. When I activate an environment (with sf and terra installed) I cannot set the CRS for or reproject spatial objects. When I run the code below I get the following error:

```
renv::init()
install.packages(c('terra', 'geodata'))

library(terra)
library(geodata)

tmin <- worldclim_tile('tmin', lon=-121, lat=38, path="~")
tmin_ta <- terra::project(tmin, "epsg:3310")
```

> Error: [project] cannot get output boundaries
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db (GDAL error 1)
> 2: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db (GDAL error 1)
> 3: [project] Cannot set raster SRS: empty srs

To me this looks like R is unable to find the GDAL projection database, but I’m not sure how to fix that. I’m not even sure where GDAL is installed on my computer, and searches for the file mentioned in the error message have come up with nothing.